# Android doesn't provide any two-State toggle buttons?

Tags: android, toggle

I am a bit new to using Android and as I look into some of the android button features, I realized that the switches or toggles are implemented differently than I expected. I see that for `ToggleButton` if you click the button, the text changes. For `Switch`, I see that there is no text but you can slide the switch left or right to show a sort of "on/off" feature. I would ideally want a two-state toggle, similar to this photo:[image]

But I can't seem to find some sort of toggle button that will do this for me. The `Switch` has no text and `ToggleButton` has text but only has one "state" that is showing. I tried to look into other ones like https://github.com/jlhonora/multistatetogglebutton but this is more for multiple states: I only want 2 states in my toggle button. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Since you're asking for a recommendation for an off-site resource (see SO FAQ), your question is off-topic. However, you do realize that anything that can handle "multiple" states can also handle two, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In android 5.0 and above it does not show text on and off . You have to specify them in xml like android: textOff and android: textOn.

Answer (score 1):

`Switch`es are what you want.

[In the documentation you can find how to change the text](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html)

> Sets the text displayed when the button is not in the checked state.
>
> Sets the text displayed when the button is in the checked state.

Java:

```
void setTextOff(CharSequence textOff)
void setTextOn(CharSequence textOn)
```

XML:

```
android:textOff
android:textOn
```