# How to adjust ToggleButtons in Android such that they have a rim and change their color?

Tags: android, togglebutton

I have 3 ToggleButtons in a row as you can see in the screenshot:
[image]

I would like to have the following layout modifications:

1. There should be rims separating the Toggle Buttons
2. The fill in color of the unchecked Toggle Buttons should be white while the fill in color of the checked Toggle Button should be green sucht that you can see which of those is checked (I will make sure programatically that only one of those can be checked)

Here is my XML layout for the Toggle Buttons inside a Liner Layout:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id ="@+id/linearLayoutForButtons"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        >


        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/button_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:background="#95f9ad"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:checked="true"
            android:textOn="Button 1"
            android:textOff="Button 1"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_8ssp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/button_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#95f9ad"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:checked="false"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_8ssp"
            android:textOn="Button 2"
            android:textOff="Button 2" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/button_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#95f9ad"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:checked="false"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_8ssp"
            android:textOn="Button 3"
            android:textOff="Button 3"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Any idea how I can do that? It should actually look similar to the ToggleButtons used here[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573178/android-doesnt-provide-any-two-state-toggle-buttons)

**Reminder**: Does anyone have an idea how to do that? I'll appreciate every comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can also create it like this

[image]

Perhaps this is more of what you are looking for. This does require some changes.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/root_view_background"
        android:padding="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_1_selector"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_2_selector"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/button1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/button1" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_3_selector"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/button2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/button1" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Drawable root_view_background.xml (This is the black outlining)

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:color="@color/black" android:width="1dp" />
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
</shape>
```

Drawable button_1_background_checked (This is the green background for the left button)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_light" />
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="3dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp" /> 
</shape>
```

Drawable button_2_background_checked (This is the green background for the middle button)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_light" />
</shape>
```

Drawable button_3_background checked (This is the green background for the right button)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_light" />
    <corners android:topRightRadius="3dp" android:bottomRightRadius="3dp" />
</shape>
```

Drawable button_1_selector (This changes the background of the first button when it's checked or not)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_1_background_checked" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

Drawable button_2_selector (This changes the background of the second button when it's checked or not)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_2_background_checked" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

Drawable button_3_selector (This changes the background of the last button when it's checked or not)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_3_background_checked" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Thanks Falco for your answer. I have to admit that I don't really know what you mean. Would you mind elaborating a little bit more on that?

Comment: @VanessaF added some examples, hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your comment and your effor Falco. As I currently busy with other things I will have a look at your solution during the next days. If I have any question, I'll just write futher comments.

Comment: Hello Falco, yes actually I was more looking into something like your 2nd example. The ToggleButtons should be somehow "connected" and only one of them should be ON (and then have a different color). It should not be possible that 2 are ON simultaneously. Is this possible?

Comment: @VanessaF Yes this is possible. Do you think you can achieve your desired result with the current example code i have provided?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As far as I see it your provided code provides the bottons that you can see in your upper picture. I would not know hot to adust it to get the buttons from the lower picture because generally I do not know how to approach the creation of such elements.

Comment: @VanessaF i added the code that creates the second example i provided, hope this helps. I presume you can handle the button behaviour by yourself

Comment: Thanks a lot Falco for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. Why do you need separate XML files for each of the 3 buttons altough the buttons are actually the same (and should behave equally)? And what do you mean by button behaviour? The on click listener implementation in Java? Yes, I can do that in the Java class of the Fragment.

Comment: @VanessaF the (checked) background of each button is different, the left one only has rounded corners on it's left top corner and left bottom corner, the middle one has no rounded corners and the right one has rounded corners on it's right top corner and right bottom corner. There are probably other ways to implement this but this was the quickest way for me to give you an example. And with the button behaviour I indeed mean the onClick implementation.

Comment: Thanks a lot Falco for your tremendous help. I upvoted and accepted your answer. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @VanessaF you are very welcome! And thanks for accepting my answer.